# Function to find and replace string in char array (streams) c++

Tags: c++, arrays, stream

I'm trying to find a way to find a way to search for a string in a char array then replace it with another string every time it occurs. I have a fair idea of what to do but the whole syntax behind streams sometimes confuses me. Anyway my code so far (and it isnt very much) is:

```
string FindWord = "the";
string ReplaceWord = "can";

int i = 0;
int SizeWord = FindWord.length();
int SizeReplace = ReplaceWord.length();

while (   Memory[i] != '\0')
{
         //now i know I can probably use a for loop and 
         //then if and else statements but im just not quite sure
    i++; //and then increment my position
}
```

Im not usually this slow :/ any ideas?

Comment: I think you mean string not stream. Streams are something else entirely.

Comment: well yeah I guess so, I'm going to read the array to a stream later on in the program.

Comment: Can you change the target to std::string as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd prefer to play around with character array after converting it to `std::string`

Following is simple to follow :-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main ()
{

char memory[ ] = "This is the char array"; 
 //{'O','r',' ','m','a','y',' ','b','e',' ','t','h','i','s','\0'};

std::string s(memory);

std::string FindWord = "the";
std::string ReplaceWord = "can";


std::size_t index;
    while ((index = s.find(FindWord)) != std::string::npos)
        s.replace(index, FindWord.length(), ReplaceWord);

std::cout<<s;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: im sorry im not familiar with the syntax std::string, what does that mean?

Comment: @newprogramer `std` a namespace. The `::` operator is the `scope` operator. It tells the compiler which class/namespace to look in for an identifier. `string` is a class in namespace `std`. I suggest you to get started with a good beginner [book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/1870232) on C++

Comment: and what about that size_t index portion?

Answer (score 0):

You need *two* for loops, one inside the other. The outer for loop goes through the `Memory` string one character at a time. The inner loop starts looking for the `FindWord` at the position you've got to in the outer loop.

This is a classic case where you need to break the problem down into smaller steps. What you are trying is probably a bit too complex for you to do in one go.

Try the following strategy

1) Write some code to *find* a string at a given position in another string, this will be the inner loop.

2) Put the code in step 1 in another loop (the outer loop) that goes through each position in the string you are searching in.

3) Now you can *find* all occurrences of one string in another, add the replace logic.